# Zend soap call for method with hyphen

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, zend-soap

I rewrite soap client file using Zend framework.

This is old method. it is working.

```
function getBassaService(){
    global $service;
    $h="127.0.0.1";
    $p="8000";

    if($service==null){
        $service = new SoapClient("/test/php/bassa.wsdl", array(
        "soap_version"   => SOAP_1_2,
        "trace"      => 1,
        "exceptions" => 1,
        "location" => "http://".$h.":".$p));
    }
    return $service;
}

function getAllDownloads(){
    global $service;
    $client = getService();
    try{
        $results = $client->__soapCall("list-all", array());
    }catch(SoapFault $e){
        print($e->faultstring);     
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This is my new code. I use Zend_Soap_Client.

```
    const HOST = "127.0.0.1";       
    const PORT = "8095";

    protected $_client; 

    public function __construct()
    {           
        $this->_client = new Zend_Soap_Client(APPLICATION_PATH ."/services/bassa.wsdl",
        array(
            "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
            "uri" => "http://". self::HOST .":". self::PORT
            )
        );
    }

    public function getAllDownloads()
    {
        $result = $this->_client->list-all();
        return $result;
    }
```

My soap server has `list-all` method. I want soap call to that method. But following error has occurred. Because method name has hyphen.

```
Notice: Undefined property: Zend_Soap_Client::$list in /home/dinuka/workspace/testzend/application/services/SoapClient.php on line 57

Fatal error: Call to undefined function all() in /home/dinuka/workspace/testzend/application/services/SoapClient.php on line 57
```

How i fixed it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strange. that's should work. it might be a a bug in ZF framework. maybe it's trying to convert the function name into a camel case function name with variables.

Try to use the magic function directly by calling:

```
$this->_client->__call('list-all', array('param1' => $param1))
```